# Internal App Sharing - Stuck on loading screen after clicking the url

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, loading, internal-app-sharing

I have an app that its being shared through internal app sharing to anyone with the url. However, some people are unable to download it, because after clicking the link, the Play Store gets stuck in a loading screen.

It's configured to whomever has the link to be able to install it, without email lists. I tried on two phones with different google accounts, only with my personal account was I able to download it (which is not in any email list). If I log with my account on the other phone, it works.

I tried adding other emails to the list and restricting access to people that are in the list, but they still got the same problem, and even leaving my email out of the list, I can still download it.

My personal account is not the developer account which is publishing the app.

The only change these last weeks was unpublishing the app from the store. Could that be the cause? Does the app need to be available on the store (it was approved, I just unpublished it)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'unpublishing' the app? Do you no longer have an active track inside the Play Console?

Comment: @IvánGarzaBermea in the advanced settings inside the console, there is an option to set the app availability (published or unpublished). I set it to unpublished because the version in the store was too old. Seems like a good cause, but then, wouldn't I be unable to download it too?

Comment: You need a version of the app published to at least one track. If it's a non-production track, you need to opt in (alpha/beta opt in via Google Play, internal you need the link found in the Play console).

Comment: @Philio thanks, man! I re-published as you and NuttyJackJ informed, and it started working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you unpublished the app, this means that public links will no longer reach your app, since it no longer exists for download.

You need to re-publish your app for other people to see it.

If I'm not mistaken you are using a link that looks like this to invite other people `https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/APP_ID` right?

If the app is published, and the users are still stuck on the invite screen, then it might be that they have multiple google accounts associated to their phone, so they have to change it accordingly.
(**The white square box at the top right corner is the one to switch accounts**)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, man! I re-published the app yesterday, and it became available on the store today, then the internal app sharing link started working again. What is the common practice regarding this situation of wanting to test the app via internal sharing url before publishing the "final/mvp" version to the store? What kind of version do you upload to the store during this?

Comment: Usually you should create a bundle release with the changes to be tested, and upload the app to the internal testing and publish it on the internal testing track. This will allow all testers to see the new update. Once it's validated by the QA, you can publish this release to production. If the release was not approved, you can bump the build number and keep on sending releases to internal testing to have a stable release, then you can publish it to the production  track. @GustavoFrançaAlbanodePaula